# Datadog browser log collection vs RUM browser monitoring

Tags: datadog

Datadog has browser log collection and RUM browser monitoring...

https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/javascript/

https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/

They both allow applications to log browser console errors and request errors.

The RUM monitoring looks a lot more comprehensive, so my question is, what does the browser log collection do that RUM does not?

I am struggling to see why someone would need to have both.

Answer (score 4):

The Browser Logs SDK gives you more control over what logs are collected, what data is included in the logs, and allows you to create arbitrary logs for various events, user interactions, etc. in your application.

The [Advanced Usage](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/javascript/#advanced-usage) section of the Browser Logs SDK Documentation goes over some of these features in more detail.